# Why doesn't Array.sorted() have default closure?

Tags: swift, closures

given the following playground fragment

```
let list = [4.2, 1.3, 7.8]
let list1 = list.sorted() { $0 < $1 }
let list2 = sorted(list)
let list3 = sorted(list) { $0 < $1}
```

I can use two forms of the free function `sorted`, with or without the closure. But there is no such opportunity with the Array.sorted() method. Is there a good reason why not? Couldn't Apple have declared it as such?

```
func sorted(isOrderedBefore: (<T>, <t>) -> Bool = { $0 < $1 }) { ...
```

(As a side question, why does the playground show `(3 times)` on the right side, instead of the resultant list for `list1` and `list3`?)

Comment: One concise alternative: `let list4 = list.sorted(<)`

Comment: @Rob:  Your simple comment actually caused a serious light bulb to light up for me. Almost worth more than the answer I granted below. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `let list2 = sorted(list)` the function

```
func sorted<C : SequenceType where C.Generator.Element : Comparable>(source: C) -> [C.Generator.Element]
```

is called. This function is only defined for sequences for which the
element type is `Comparable`, i.e. can be compared with `<`.

On the other hand, it is *not possible* to define an array extension
method `sorted()` which applies only to arrays with comparable elements,
compare

- [Array extension to remove object by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value): "You cannot write a method on a generic type that is more restrictive on the template."
- [Is it possible to make an Array extension in Swift that is restricted to one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350941/is-it-possible-to-make-an-array-extension-in-swift-that-is-restricted-to-one-cla)

Answer (score 4):

A default closure would only be viable if the method only worked for `T` that conforms to the `Comparable` protocol. Not every type has the `<` or `>` operators defined.

If you look closely, the free function form comes in two flavors. One for all `T`, and one for `T` that are `Comparable`.

Comment: But wouldn't the compiler be able to note that the default wasn't going to work for the receiver type and yell at you?

Comment: Or put another way maybe, if I attempt to `sort()` T's that aren't `Comparable`, the compiler will chose the "needs closure" one and yell at me if I don't provide a closure. I'm unclear why it can't do that in this case as well.

Comment: A generic type on T cannot have a method that restricts T further, i.e Array<T> cannot have a method that operates only on <T: Comparable>, I find it mildly annoying actually.