# Using append in generic function inside Array extension

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I found this obscure problem when creating generic function inside Array extension. Let's say I have User class that I'll use to create array:

```
class User : NSObject {
    let name : String
    let surname : String

    init(name : String, surname : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
    }

    override var description : String {
        return self.name + " " + self.surname
    }
}
```

Note that I need it to be subclass of NSObject. Now let's create two users and add them to array of users.

```
var user1 = User(name: "Jimmy", surname: "Page")
var user2 = User(name: "David", surname: "Guilmour")

var users = Array<User>()
users.append(user1)
users.append(user2)
```

Now I need an Array extension with function specific to Array, or any other subclass of User, that will add some test users to any array of users. Reason I write it inside extension and not my own type is because i want to check it's type using `if let something = something as [User]`. If I build my own type I would not be able to do that.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func addTestUsers<T : User>() {
        var testUser1 = User(name: "King", surname: "Brown")
        var testUser2 = User(name: "Carlos", surname: "Santana")
        self.append(testUser1)
        self.append(testUser2)
    }
}
```

The problem comes when using append function or any other function that can somehow mutate the initial Array.

Error : `Cannot invoke append with argument list of type (User)`

I know it's because extension is never specified as extension of Array of User, but as I can see there is no way I can do this.

Comment: You *cannot* define an Array extension method which applies to arrays of User only, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350941/is-it-possible-to-make-an-array-extension-in-swift-that-is-restricted-to-one-cla.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in @Martin R's comment, if you have a look at [Array extension to remove object by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value), the highest voted answer suggests writing a function that takes an array as an argument, in your case you could do something like:

```
func addTestUsers(inout array: [User]) {
    let user1 = User(name: "King", surname: "Brown")
    let user2 = User(name: "Carlos", surname: "Santana")
    array += [user1, user2]
}
```

You could then use this like so:

```
var array = [User(name: "Jimmy", surname: "Page")]
addTestUsers(&array) // [Jimmy Page, King Brown, Carlos Santana]
```

If you are intending to create subclasses of `User`, however, the previous method is unsuitable since you won't be able to pass an array of subclasses as the argument. In this situation you could override `addTestUsers` to accept your subclass, but a more elegant solution could be:

```
func addTestUsers<T: User>(inout array: [T]) {
    let user1 = T(name: "King", surname: "Brown")
    let user2 = T(name: "Carlos", surname: "Santana")
    array += [user1, user2]
}
```

For the previous function to work you need to mark `init(name : String, surname : String)` in `User` as `required`:

```
class User : NSObject {
    // ... 
    required init(name : String, surname : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
    } 
    // ... 
}
```

Marking it as `required` means any subclasses of `User` **must** implement `init(name : String, surname : String)`, therefore it's safe to use `T(name: "...", surname: "...")` in `addTestUsers`.