# Template/Generics specialization in Swift with extensions

Tags: swift

I would like to extend Array to create a contact list.

One of the new methods would looks like:

```
extension Array {
    func contactWithChatId<Contact>(chat_id: String) -> Contact? {
        for contact in self {
            if contact.chat_id == chat_id {
                return contact
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

However, I didn't found any way to express this in Swift.
Is it possible to do it, and how to ?

### Solution:

```
extension Array {
    func contactWithChatId<T>(chat_id: String) -> Contact? {
        if self.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        precondition(self.first is Contact , "Should be a Contact list")
        for contact in self {
            let contact = contact as! Contact
            if contact.chat_id == chat_id {
                return contact
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You *cannot* write extension methods that apply only to a restricted type of the generic element type, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value.

Comment: @MartinR I guess this is an answer :)

Comment: Also answered here: [Is it possible to make an Array extension in Swift that is restricted to one class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350941/is-it-possible-to-make-an-array-extension-in-swift-that-is-restricted-to-one-cla)