# Swift Array extension only for certain type of Array

Tags: ios, swift, swift-extensions

If I want to make an `Array` extension, but only do an extension for an `Array` of type `[UIView]`, is that possible in Swift?

Currently I'm just doing a normal `extension Array` with a precondition that the `Array` only holds elements of type `UIView`, but it seems like there must be a better way.

Here is how I'm currently doing it:

```
extension Array {

    mutating func sortByVerticalPositionTopToBottomIn(rootView: UIView) {
        precondition(arrayConsistsOfOnlyType(UIView), "This method should only be used for arrays of UIViews.")

        self.sort {
            let firstObj = $0 as! UIView
            let secondObj = $1 as! UIView
            return firstObj.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: rootView).y < secondObj.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: rootView).y
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That is still not possible (as far as I know), but in Swift 2 something *similar* can be done with "protocol extensions". In Swift 1.x you would need a global function. See (for example) the various answers to [Array extension to remove object by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value) and [Is it possible to make an Array extension in Swift that is restricted to one class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350941/is-it-possible-to-make-an-array-extension-in-swift-that-is-restricted-to-one-cla)

Comment: @MartinR not possible but something similar – you mean you can only extend the protocol not `Array` specifically?

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: Yes, that's what I meant with "protocol extension". Let me know if my comment is wrong or if you disagree about the duplicate, then I'll reopen the question.

Comment: @MartinR Was just checking that was what you meant as I interpreted similar to mean not quite what you want – personally I would say that means it _is_ possible since in this use case extending the protocol rather than Array specifically is just as good if not better. Agree its a dupe.