# Simple Swift Array Extension

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground

Trying to extend Array type to use binary sorting to insert elements in order.
Here's my playground code:

```
  extension Array  {

      func insertionIndexOf(elem: T , isOrderedBefore: (T, T) -> Bool) -> Int {
       var lo = 0
       var hi = self.count - 1
       while lo <= hi {
        let mid = (lo + hi)/2
        if isOrderedBefore(self[mid], elem) {
            lo = mid + 1
        } else if isOrderedBefore(elem, self[mid]) {
            hi = mid - 1
        } else {
            return mid
        }
    }
        return 0 
 }


  mutating func insertOrdered(elem: T){
     let index = self.insertionIndexOf(elem, isOrderedBefore: { (a , b)     in return (a > b) } )
     return insert(elem, atIndex: index)
}
```

}

I get a compiler error: "cannot invoke insertionIndexOf with argument list of type ( T , isOrderedBefore: (_, _) -> _) "

The curious thing is, if I use instead:

```
    mutating func insertOrdered(elem: T){
         let index = self.insertionIndexOf(elem, isOrderedBefore: { (a , b) in return false } )
         return insert(elem, atIndex: index)
        }
```

The compiler calms down but the array insertion will not be ordered, :( of course.
Please any ideas?? Thank you.

(using Xcode 6.3 beta 2  -  Swift 1.2)

Comment: That code looks familiar http://stackoverflow.com/a/26679191/1187415 :) – Note that the final `return 0` should be `return lo`.

Comment: @MartinR  Yes :) I used your example for a binary search to add come context to my problem. I've been playing around with extension a bit. Sorry, just forgot to drop a link to your code. Hope no harm done.

Comment: @MartinR  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107928/swift-map-extension-for-set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to evaluate `a > b`, but `T` may not be `Comparable`. It's not possible to write an extension like this today. What you'd like to be able to say is:

```
extension Array where T: Comparable {
```

But that's not possible in Swift currently. The compiler team has indicated that it is a priority, but we don't know when it may come to Swift.

Your best approach is to either make this a function:

```
func insertOrdered<T: Comparable>(inout xs: [T], x: T)
```

Or make a new object that HAS-A array:

```
struct OrderedArray<T: Comparable> : ... {
    var values: [T]
    func insertionIndexOf(elem: T , isOrderedBefore: (T, T) -> Bool) -> Int
    mutating func inserOrdered(elem: T)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million Rob! I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 5):

As of Swift 2, this can be achieved with *protocol extension methods*:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Comparable, Index == Int {

    func insertionIndexOf(elem: Generator.Element) -> Int {
        var lo = 0
        var hi = self.count - 1
        while lo <= hi {
            let mid = (lo + hi)/2
            if self[mid] < elem {
                lo = mid + 1
            } else if elem < self[mid] {
                hi = mid - 1
            } else {
                return mid // found at position mid
            }
        }
        return lo // not found, would be inserted at position lo
    }
}

extension RangeReplaceableCollectionType where Generator.Element : Comparable, Index == Int {

    mutating func insertOrdered(elem: Generator.Element) {
        let index = self.insertionIndexOf(elem)
        self.insert(elem, atIndex: index)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var ar = [1, 3, 5, 7]
ar.insertOrdered(6)
print(ar) // [1, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

The methods are not defined for `struct Array` directly, but for some
protocol to which `Array` conforms, and which provides the necessary
methods.

For the first method, that is `CollectionType` because that
provides the (reading) subscript access, and the collection element
type is required to be `Comparable`.

The second method mutates
the collection, here the more restrictive protocol 
`RangeReplaceableCollectionType` is required.