# Swift map(_:) extension for Set() ?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

```
  let numberSet = Set(1...11)
  let divideSet = numberSet.map({  $0 / 10 }) 
  //Error: Set does not have a member named map   :(
```

Swift 1.2 supports `Set()` for unordered collections, but `map(_:)` doesn't seem to work on Sets, so i decide to get smart on my playground and tried:

```
 let stringSet = Set(map(numberSet, { String($0)}))
 println(stringSet)
 stringSet =  ["2", "11", "1", "8", "6", "4", "3", "9", "7", "10", "5]
```

This seemed to work.
So I tried extending Set:

```
    extension Set {
        func map<U>(transform: (T) -> U) -> Set<U> {
        return Set(Swift.map(self, transform))  }
    }
   Error: "couldn't find initialiser for Set(T) that accepts argument of type U"
```

And i think there is a good reason why it doesn’t work, like this example here:

```
   let smarDividSet = Set(map(numberSet, {$0 / 2})) 
   println(smarDividSet)
   smartDividSet = "[5, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3]” 
  //Somehow elements is the Set are going missing.
```

Any ideas on how to extend Set to use map(_:) reliably ?. 
Thank guys.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** Quite a lot changed with Swift 2 and 3. The generic
placeholder of `Set` is now `Element` instead of `T`, and all
collections have a `map()` method which returns an *array.*

There were also good arguments given about the problems of a `Set -> Set` mapping (such as different elements mapping to the same result).
On the other hand, there may be a use-case for such a mapping,
so here is an update for **Swift 3** (now using a different name).

```
extension Set {
    func setmap<U>(transform: (Element) -> U) -> Set<U> {
        return Set<U>(self.lazy.map(transform))
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let numberSet = Set(1...11)
let divideSet = numberSet.setmap { $0 / 2 }
print(divideSet) // [5, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
```

---

*(Old answer:)* You were almost there. For some reason, the generic type of the
returned set must be specified explicitly:

```
extension Set {
    func map<U>(transform: (T) -> U) -> Set<U> {
        return Set<U>(Swift.map(self, transform))
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let numberSet = Set(1...11)

let divideSet = numberSet.map { $0 / 2 }
println(divideSet) // [5, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
```

The resulting set has less elements because the integer division
`$0 / 2` *truncates* the quotient, e.g. both 4/2 and 5/2 map to
the same element 2. This does not happen with floating point division:

```
let floatdivideSet = numberSet.map { Double($0) / 2.0 }
println(floatdivideSet) // [4.0, 5.0, 4.5, 5.5, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5]
```

Another possible implementation is

```
extension Set {
    func map<U>(transform: (T) -> U) -> Set<U> {
        return Set<U>(lazy(self).map(transform))
    }
}
```

Here `lazy(self)` returns a `LazyForwardCollection` which has
a `map()` method and that returns a `LazyForwardCollection` again.
The advantage might be that no intermediate array is created.

Comment: Good news is that Swift 1.2 will support the `Set` data type natively.

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks Martin!  Yes, after I posted the question I understood the reason why the set was truncated, because there are never repeating elements in Sets, unlike arrays or dictionaries. 
Many thanks for this, and again, I'm truly sorry for the binary search thing.

Comment: @Erik_at_Digit Yes Erik :)  The thing is, there's no direct native support for `map(_:)` ,   `reduce (_:combine:)` on Set() as this point. The extension Martin has above fixes that.

Comment: How can it work as you don't define `T`. At least with Swift 3 it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Martin. A use case in my case would be the array of permissions you give to Facebook SDK and the Set of declined permissions you get back.

Answer (score 9):

The issue with `Set.map(_:)` is the same with `Dictionary.map(_:)`, and they didn't implement it in the `Swift` module (standard library) because there's actually *no correct way* to implement it. The reason is: `map`ping isn't just enumerating (which you can do with any `SequenceType` in a `for-in`), but it's transforming (with the argument closure) each value into another. So you would expect that the result would have the all the `transform(element)` in it, but guess what, if the values are the same they collapse (for `Dictionary`s only the keys behave this way).

e.g. (with the proposed implementation)

`Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).map { 1 }.count == 1`

That's also why `Swift.map` returns an `Array` and not the same type of `SequenceType`/`CollectionType` passed as the `source` argument.

To digress slightly, `Dictionary` (as said before) has the same issue on the key values (which is basically a `Set`), so any `map` that works either on the `Set<K>` or the `Set<(K, V)>` doesn't ensure a consistent mapping, but one that changes the values only would be ok. It wouldn't be a true `map` though since `Dictionary`s are collections of tuples, not on value only. So there could be something similar to `mapValues` which would be correct, but still not a true `map` on the collection.

## TL;DR

`map` is really useful but be careful on what you're actually doing, because you can't *really* do a `map` from `Set` to `Set`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you want to map a set, just make it an array first using `Array(set).map { ... }`

Comment: I don't agree at all.  This is exactly how map works in Haskell, and it seems to me to be the natural use.  Certainly it's the usual way of lifting a function on a data type a set of elements of that type in math.  If f:X->Also, since a set is unordered and a list is ordered, it's hard to see how one would use the construct you appear to think is the natural.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up typing the the comment, and it worn't let me edit it any more.  Here I go again: I'm afraid I can't agree.  This is exactly how map on sets works in Haskell, and it seems to me to be the natural use.  Certainly it's the usual way of lifting a function on a data type to a function on a set of elements of that type in math.  If  f is a function from X to Y, then define f from P(X) to P(Y) (P is power set) by fS) = {f(s) | s in S}.  Also, since a set is unordered and a list is ordered, it's hard to see how to use the construct you appear to think is the natural one.

Answer (score 1):

As of Swift 2.0 the `CollectionType` protocol (implemented by `Set`) has a `map` method.

Comment: Thankx Matthieu! Nice info :)

Answer (score 0):

I made an extension for `Set`:

```
extension Set {

    /// Map, but for a `Set`.
    /// - Parameter transform: The transform to apply to each element.
    func map<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> Set<T> {
        var tempSet = Set<T>()

        try forEach {
            tempSet.insert(try transform($0))
        }

        return tempSet
    }
}
```

For example:

```
let someSet: Set<Int> = [1, 3, 5, 7]
print(someSet.map { $0 + 1 })

// Prints:  [2, 6, 8, 4]
```