# Error Cannot invoke initilizer of type 'Box<T>'

Tags: swift, generics

Why this is not allowed?

```
class Box<T>{
    let value: T
    init(_ value:T){
        self.value = value
    }

    func map<U>( f: T -> U)->Box<U>{
        return Box(f(self.value))
    }
}
```

Error at `return Box(f(self.value))`:

> Error : Cannot invoke initilizer of type 'Box<T>' with an argument list of type '(U)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the type for `Box` object that you're returning:

```
class Box<T> {
    let value: T
    init(_ value:T){
        self.value = value
    }

    func map<U>(f: (T) -> (U)) -> Box<U> {
        return Box<U>(f(self.value))
    }
}
```

Within the context of the `Box<T>` class implementation, any references to `Box` are assumed to be `Box<T>` unless you explicitly specify the type (as I did with `Box<U>`, in the `return` statement, above).

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler be able to infer that from the context? – But the same happened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107928/swift-map-extension-for-set .

Comment: Yes. What I meant is: Should this be considered as a compiler bug?

Comment: @MartinR I'd say yes since `let val: Int = 1 ; let foo = Box(val)` doesn't give an error, but the work around is trivial.

Comment: @MartinR - I might not be inclined to call this a "bug". There's a certain simplicity and logic to the existing implementation. I can make arguments for both approaches.

Comment: @JeremyP - Sure, if you do that code outside the `Box<T>` implementation it works. But if you do that code within the `Box<T>` implementation, you get the same error that the code in your question does.

Comment: @Rob I have accepted the answer as it fixes the error.. but I still not understand, why compiler should throw error in Box<T> implementation.

Comment: We can make educated guesses why they designed it the way they did, but rather than engaging in conjecture, this question might best be directed to the [Apple Swift Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/community/tools/languages/swift). There might be someone in Cupertino who can tell you precisely why they did it that way.

Comment: @Rob yes I know it gives the error inside Box and not outside Box.  That was my point, the behaviour is inconsistent.