# How to use a map method on Set<T>?

Tags: swift

Sorry for the stupid question, but I can't find the answer in Swift documentation...

```
let set: Set<String> = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"]
let res: Set<String> = set.map { return $0+"_bar" } // Ambiguous reference to member 'map'
```

How can I use map method on Set<T>?

p.s. Suggested "[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107928/swift-map-extension-for-set)" question: 1) about other issue; 2) answers doesn't work in current Swift version

Comment: @i_am_jorf I'm not sure – it seems in earlier versions Set didn't has a "map" method – that's what that question about. In current version, Set has own "map" method, but I can't use it because of the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `set.map` (really `CollectionType.map`) returns an `Array`, not a `Set`.  Hence:

```
let res = set.map { $0 + "_bar" }
```

Works and leaves you with `[String]` which you can convert back to a `Set<String>` with the constructor:

```
let res : Set<String> = Set(set.map{$0 + "_bar"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the answer is pretty easy – thanks to other community for the help!

```
let set: Set<String> = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"]
let res: Set<String> = Set(set.map { return $0+"_bar" })
```