# Iterate and modify Struct in a Set

Tags: swift

I have a `Set` of `Ints`:

```
var mySet = Set<Int>()

mySet.insert(1)
mySet.insert(2)
// ....

// How to iterate over it and, for example, add 1 to each element?
for (index, _) in mySet.enumerated() {
    // How to subscript? A set is unordered!
}
```

I want to modify `mySet` and do some extra calculations on it. How can I make modify each element in `mySet`? I can create another temp `mySet Set` and add copies to that `Set` and later on, assign the temp `mySet Set` to the original `mySet`, but I was wondering if there was another better way.

```
// Ugly method?
var mySetTemp = Set<Int>()

for value in mySet {
    mySetTemp.insert(value + 1)
}

mySet = mySetTemp
```

Is there a way I can do above without creating extra objects, just for the sake of modifying an original value in an iteration of a `Set` of `Structs`?

When the `Set` was an `Array`, I could easily do it by subscripting elements by index, but since `Sets` are unordered, I can not do it.

Comment: Set conforms to Collection, but not to MutableCollection, so you cannot mutate the elements in-place.

Comment: Related: [Swift map(_:) extension for Set() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29107928/1187415)

Comment: @MartinR Ow that is surely related :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign `mySet` as mapped `mySet` converted to `Set`

```
mySet = Set(mySet.map { $0 + 1 })
```

Comment: I mean it is just adding 2 values together, the return value doesn't get used.

Comment: You would have to do something like `mySet = Set(mySet.map { $0 + 1})`

Comment: @dan I think that doesn't do good any as well. $0 + 1 returns an int right? But nothing gets done with the return value

Comment: @J.Doe What do you mean? It returns an array of the modified values, then converts it into a new set.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Don't worry about creating duplicates until you identify it as an actual performance bottleneck.