# More idiomatic way to leverage Swift for this sorted set algorithm?

Tags: swift

I'm modelling a time series log in Swift using just an `Array` and a custom class that looks like:

```
class StatusEvent {
    var status:ValveStatus // this is just an enum
    var begin:NSDate
}
```

As I get updates to my log, I maintain the invariant that there are no duplicates (inferred by matching times) and that they are sorted in order by the `begin` property. My three uses for this data are:

1. Access the latest (last) element (this happens a lot)
2. Enumerate them in order (for visualizing the time series)
3. Adding new values to the list, which happens on periodic updates, but not that much

I can do some quick checks like "is this an add past end or before front" which take care of a lot of them, but when I detect the case where I've got to insert somewhere in the middle, I came up with the following:

```
var begin = oldestLogEvent.begin
for index in 1..<self.statusLog.count {
    let event = self.statusLog[index]
    let end = event.begin
    if newEvent.begin == end {
        return false;
    }
    if begin < newEvent.begin && newEvent.begin < end {
        self.statusLog.insert(newEvent, atIndex: index)
        return true;
    }
    begin = end;
}
```

I return a `Bool` indicating whether an insertion happened or not.

Having ported this from Objective-C, I'm curious if Swift gives me some tools/idioms that would solve this "search for insertion point and conditionally insert" algorithm?

I'm open to using some other than an Array and simple event class; I looked at using a tree, but while that makes the insert potentially faster, I think it would cost more memory as well as make enumeration and last element access (my primary use cases) slower.

Comment: Why don't you just append and then sort? Sure, that would not be very efficient if you had 10000 elements and you did it a lot, but doing it for a small array once in a while won't bring the universe crashing down about your ears.

Comment: This might possibly me helpful: [How do I insert an element at the correct position into a sorted array in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678362/how-do-i-insert-an-element-at-the-correct-position-into-a-sorted-array-in-swift)

Comment: I have considered doing exactly that. Just add and sort. Though I have to first check for existing so I don't add duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in Swift, if you have no good reason to make something a class, make it a struct.

Second, in answer to your actual question, what I would do is far less computer-sciency than you seem to be envisioning: I would just make StatusEvent a Comparable (i.e. it knows that one StatusEvent is bigger than another if its `begin` is bigger) and then just append a new Status Event and sort the array on `<`.

This could have a second benefit; you will have to make StatusEvent an Equatable, and if you decide that two StatusEvents are equal if their `begin` are the same, you can just use `find` to determine whether a StatusEvent with the same `begin` is already present in the array.

Here's a simplified example (I'm using Int instead of Date):

```
func == (lhs:StatusEvent, rhs:StatusEvent) -> Bool {
    return lhs.begin == rhs.begin
}
func < (lhs:StatusEvent, rhs:StatusEvent) -> Bool {
    return lhs.begin < rhs.begin
}
struct StatusEvent : Comparable {
    var begin : Int = 0
}
var arr = [StatusEvent(begin:3), StatusEvent(begin:2)]
let se = StatusEvent(begin:1)
if find(arr,se) == nil { // not already present
    arr.append(se)
    arr.sort(<)
}
```

Comment: Even if you decide to go with a binary search instead of sorting, making StatusEvent a Comparable is probably going to save you some work.

Comment: "First of all, in Swift, if you have no good reason to make something a class, make it a struct..." Can I ask why? I would have thought just the opposite? What would be the reasons? If it's in your book already... I have it, just give me a page number. :)

Comment: It is, but I'll just summarize :) struct is the Swift object type par excellence. class adds a bunch of heavyweight stuff (inheritance) plus it turns this thing into a reference type instead of a value type (big memory management complications), and I don't see you using any of that, so a struct seems more appropriate.