# Stridable Protocol

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert the following Swift 2.3 code:

```
//Example usage:
//(0 ..< 778).binarySearch { $0 < 145 } // 145
extension CollectionType where Index: RandomAccessIndexType {

    /// Finds such index N that predicate is true for all elements up to
    /// but not including the index N, and is false for all elements
    /// starting with index N.
    /// Behavior is undefined if there is no such N.
    func binarySearch(predicate: Generator.Element -> Bool)
        -> Index {
        var low = startIndex
        var high = endIndex
        while low != high {
            let mid = low.advancedBy(low.distanceTo(high) / 2)
            if predicate(self[mid]) {
                low = mid.advancedBy(1)
            } else {
                high = mid
            }
        }
        return low
    }
}
```

into Swift 3 as follows:

```
//Example usage:
//(0 ..< 778).binarySearch { $0 < 145 } // 145
extension Collection where Index: Strideable {

    /// Finds such index N that predicate is true for all elements up to
    /// but not including the index N, and is false for all elements
    /// starting with index N.
    /// Behavior is undefined if there is no such N.
    func binarySearch(predicate: (Generator.Element) -> Bool)
        -> Index {
        var low = startIndex
        var high = endIndex
        while low != high {
            let mid = low.advanced(by: low.distance(to: high) / 2)
            if predicate(self[mid]) {
                low = mid.advanced(to: 1)
            } else {
                high = mid
            }
        }
        return low
    }
}
```

The error

> Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'self.Index.Stride' and 'Int'

is thrown at `let mid = low.advanced(by: low.distance(to: high) / 2)`

Any help on how to fix it?

Comment: Is your Swift 2 code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33674192/1187415? You should add a link to the original if quoting code from other sources.

Comment: Yes, thanks for finding the link.  I couldn't track that down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift 3, "Collections move their index", compare
 [A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md) on Swift evolution. In particular, you don't call `advancedBy()` on an index, 
but an `index()` method on the collection to advance indices.

So your method would be implemented in Swift 3 as

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {

    func binarySearch(predicate: (Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> Index {
        var low = startIndex
        var high = endIndex
        while low != high {
            let mid = index(low, offsetBy: distance(from: low, to: high)/2)
            if predicate(self[mid]) {
                low = index(after: mid)
            } else {
                high = mid
            }
        }
        return low
    }
}
```

The same method would also compile (and work) as an extension of the
more general `Collection` type, but – as Vadim Yelagin correctly remarked,
is very inefficient if the index/offset calculations cannot be done in
constant time.

Comment: It still makes sense to define this only on RandomAccessCollection because the algorithm is ineffective unless distance and offset can be computed in constant time.