# Beginner Swift 3: How to find pairs in array that add up to given number

Tags: arrays, swift, sequence

Need to loop through an array and say whether there are any pairs of numbers that sum to 8

e.g. [1,2,4,4] = yes

Can get it working with lots of nested if statements but this will be impractical if the array changes.

What I'd ideally like to do is say for i if i + (i.indexPosition +1 {Number next to i})) == 8 then print true, if not false, then move onto the next iteration of numbersSet

Wondering if someone knew some better logic that could be used here? Many thanks!!

E.g.

```
var numbersSet = [1, 2, 4, 4]

for i in numbersSet2 {

    var targetSum = 8

    if i + numbersSet2[1] == targetSum {

        print("True")
    } else { // Nested if statements here

        print("False")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to check all sums `numbers[i] + numbers[j]` where
`i < j`, and the easiest way to do so is a nested loop like this:

```
func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> Bool {

    for i in 0..<numbers.count {
        for j in i+1..<numbers.count {
            if numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The array lookups can be avoided by using the `enumerated()` method
and array slices:

```
func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> Bool {

    for (i, x) in numbers.enumerated() {
        for y in numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count] {
            if x + y == target {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Here `x` is the current element of the outer loop and `i` its
index. `y` is the current element of the inner loop which starts
enumerating at `i + 1`.

Example:

```
print(checkPairs(in: [1, 2, 4, 4], forSum: 8))
print(checkPairs(in: [1, 2, 4, 4], forSum: 7))
```

The above function *could* be written more compactly as

```
func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> Bool {

    return numbers.enumerated().contains(where: { (i, x) -> Bool in
        numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count].contains(target - x)
    })
}
```

If the given numbers are in *non-decreasing* order then you can
improve the performance by terminating the inner loop
if the target sum cannot be reached:

```
func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> Bool {

    for (i, x) in numbers.enumerated() {
        for y in numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count] {
            if x + y == target {
                return true
            }
            if x + y > target {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

For an array of *non-decreasing* numbers an even more efficient
solution would be to do a *binary search* for `target - x` 
for each array element `x`. Here is a possible binary search
implementation (a variant of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226976/1187415):

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Comparable {

    func binarySearch(element: Iterator.Element) -> Bool {
        var low = startIndex
        var high = endIndex
        while low != high {
            let mid = index(low, offsetBy: distance(from: low, to: high)/2)
            if self[mid] < element {
                low = index(after: mid)
            } else if element < self[mid] {
                high = mid
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

which can then be used as

```
func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> Bool {

    return numbers.enumerated().contains(where: { (i, x) -> Bool in
        numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count].binarySearch(element: target - x)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Above all answers are fine but all are returning Bool value, Thus I am writing a solution to store all possible pairs in a dictionary and print them.

The below solution will avoid reiteration, Thus complexity is minimized.

```
var numbers = [13,2,4,5,6,3,7,90,11,10,12,1,8,9]
var dictionary1 : [Int : Int] = [:]
var j = 0
func findPair(numbers : [ Int ] , number : Int) -> [Int : Int] {
    
    for (i , _) in numbers.enumerated() {
        
        j = i
        while j < numbers.count {
            
            if i != j {
                let addition = numbers[i] + numbers[j]
                if addition == number {
                    dictionary1[numbers[i]] = numbers[j]
                }
            }
            j += 1
        }
    }
    return dictionary1
}

let result = findPair(numbers: numbers, number: 11)
print(dictionary1)
```

**Output - [10: 1, 4: 7, 5: 6, 3: 8, 2: 9]**

These are all pairs whose addition is a given number. i.e 11

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift)  [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested for loops with indexes:

```
for (firstIndex, firstElement) in numbersSet.enumerated() {
    for (secondIndex, secondElement) in numbersSet.enumerated() {
        if firstIndex != secondIndex && firstElement + secondElement == 8 {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two pointer technique.

Time Complexity:  O(n)

Other solutions mentioned here have Time Complexity:  O(n2)

```
func isPairSum()-> Bool{

let array = [3, 5, 9, 2, 8, 10, 11]
let sum = 22


var i = 0
var j = array.count - 1

while i<j {
    
    let valueSum = array[i] + array[j]
    if valueSum == sum {
        return true
    }
    
    else if valueSum > sum {
        j -= 1
    }
    
    else if valueSum < sum {
        i += 1
    }
    
}
return false
```

}

And If you want the values of the pair, instead of returning Bool, you can return Tuple of type Int.