# Find all the unique pairs whose sum will be equal to a given sum

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I want to find all the unique pairs whose sum will be equal to a given sum. I implement a solution but it returns only the first pair that it finds.

```
func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> String {    
    for (i, x) in numbers.enumerated() {
        for y in numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count] {
            if x + y == target {
                return ("There is a pair that sums \(target): \(x)+\(y)=\(target)")
            }
        }
    }
    return "no pair"
}

print (checkPairs(in: [1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 5, 3], forSum: 8))
```

Output:

```
There is a pair that sums 8: 1+7=8
```

Comment: You do `return` on a Single value. Instead use an Array to hold all the pair that "worked", append a new pair when needed and return it?

Comment: @Larme is it good to use a while loop to print all pairs sum 8 ?

Comment: Your code [looks somewhat familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43733754/1187415) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exit the function early by calling `return` when the first pair is found. Instead, you should return an array of tuples containing the pairs, iterate over all pairs and add the ones satisfying the requirements to the return array.

```
func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> [(Int,Int)] {
    var pairs = [(Int,Int)]()
    for (i, x) in numbers.enumerated() {
        for y in numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count] {
            if x + y == target {
                pairs.append((x,y))
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs
}

print(checkPairs(in: [1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 5, 3], forSum: 8))
```

Output:

> [(1, 7), (4, 4), (5, 3)]

If you're looking for unique pairs, you can define a custom type holding the pair of numbers and return a `Set` instead of an `Array` (the custom type is needed, since you cannot make a `Tuple` conform to `Hashable`, which is needed to be able to add elements to a `Set`).

```
struct Pair: Hashable {
    let smaller:Int
    let bigger:Int
    
    init(_ a:Int, _ b:Int) {
        if a < b {
            smaller = a
            bigger = b
        } else {
            smaller = b
            bigger = a
        }
    }
}

extension Pair: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description:String {
        return "\((smaller,bigger))"
    }
}

func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> Set<Pair> {
    var pairs = Set<Pair>()
    for (i, x) in numbers.enumerated() {
        for y in numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count] {
            if x + y == target {
                pairs.insert(Pair(x,y))
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs
}

print(checkPairs(in: [1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 5, 3], forSum: 8))
print(checkPairs(in: [1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 5, 3, 4, 1], forSum: 8))
```

Output:

> [(4, 4), (3, 5), (1, 7)]
>
> [(4, 4), (3, 5), (1, 7)]

Comment: If we're looking for **unique** pairs, then this doesn't work for arrays like: `[1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 5, 3, 4, 1]`

Comment: @Carpsen90 you're absolutely right, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

here is one of options you can do

```
    let array = [1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 5, 3]
let target = 8


func checkPairs(in numbers: [Int], forSum target: Int) -> String {
    var pairs = ""
    for (i, x) in numbers.enumerated() {
        for y in numbers[i+1 ..< numbers.count] {
            if x + y == target {
                pairs += ("There is a pair that sums \(target): \(x)+\(y)=\(target)\n")
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs
}

print(checkPairs(in: array, forSum: target))
```

> output will be  There is a pair that sums 8: 1+7=8 There is a pair
>   that sums 8: 4+4=8 There is a pair that sums 8: 5+3=8

Comment: Returning a single `String` with that formatting is a really bad idea. It's really hard to parse that if you need it later for further processing and it's also quite bad to just read through that string due to the huge amount of duplicate information in it.

Comment: maybe he wants to show it like that in a label then yours is complicated to show thats why I said its a one of the options it depends on what he wants to do