# Which Swift collection protocol to extend to add binary search

Tags: swift, collections, protocols, binary-search

I want to implement some binary search like functions that operate on collections of sorted elements that are randomly accessible (in constant time), and where index arithmetic is supported (for deriving a mid point). I could add these methods as an extension or `Array`. However, I'd prefer to add them to a more generic protocol that supports the necessary functionality so that my extension can be used more widely.

Which protocol should I use, and how do I go about finding such protocols in future? I did a search for "Swift collection protocol hierarchy" and similar, and I've not found anything useful beyond various red herrings.

Comment: You *can* implement it for arbitrary collections (example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226976/1187415). A [RandomAccessCollection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/randomaccesscollection) guarantees that you can move the index in O(1) time.

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://www.skilled.io/u/playgroundscon/sequence-and-collection-swift

Answer (score 1):

For the binary search you need to find the "midpoint" between two
index positions, and that is possible for any [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection), because
its associated  [`IndexDistance`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/indexdistance) is required to be a `SignedInteger`.

A possible implementation (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226976/1187415) is

```
extension Collection {

    func binarySearch(predicate: (Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> Index {
        var low = startIndex
        var high = endIndex
        while low != high {
            let mid = index(low, offsetBy: distance(from: low, to: high)/2)
            if predicate(self[mid]) {
                low = index(after: mid)
            } else {
                high = mid
            }
        }
        return low
    }
}
```

Here [`distance(from:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1784282-distance) returns a `IndexDistance` which can be divided by 2 because it
conforms to `SignedInteger` (and therefore to `IntegerArithmetic`), the result
can be used in [`index(_:offsetBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1781645-index).

The documentation of both methods states that the
complexity is

> O(1) if the collection conforms to RandomAccessCollection; otherwise, O(n), where n is the absolute value of n.

So you can implement it as an extension of `RandomAccessCollection`
if you want to guarantee that it is only used on collections for which
moving indices and measuring distances is a O(1) operation.

Or you implement it as an extension of `Collection` so that it can
be used universally. It will be "fast" (in the above sense) when
called on a  `RandomAccessCollection` and might be "slow" otherwise.