# Finding an Element within an Array efficiently [Swift]

Tags: swift

Currently using the following to find a match within an array, but I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing such a check.

```
for player in team.roster {
     if id == player.id {
          return player.name
     }
}
```

Basically taking a variable that is given, a player id, and looping through a team roster to find a matching id, which given the size of the team is okay, but in the event a similar check is done on a larger data set what would be a better way to handle this?

Comment: use default property ```team.roster.first{where: .....```

Comment: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first)

Comment: If the entries are sorted by their id then you can do a binary search. Or you can maintain an index. Otherwise you'll always have to traverse the array to find a matching entry. Using `first(where:)` does not make it more efficient.

Comment: To clarify, by "maintain an index", Martin is talking about building a dictionary that maps IDs to players. You pay some up-front cost, but subsequent repeated look-ups become faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default property `first{ condition }`

```
    let id = 4
    
    let roster: [TeamMember] = [.init(id: 1, name: "Abishek", age: 19),
                               .init(id: 2, name: "Dinesh", age: 22),
                               .init(id: 3, name: "Praveen", age: 24),
                               .init(id: 4, name: "Sam", age: 25),
                               .init(id: 5, name: "David", age: 21)]
let firstMember = roster.first{$0.id == id}

print(firstMember)
print(firstMember?.name)
```

Output

```
Optional(TeamMember(id: 4, name: "Sam", age: 25.0))
Optional("Sam")
```

Comment: This is tidier, but equivalent, performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

@Shabnam Siddiqui answer is Swifty and I would use it most of the time, but the binary search is worth to know as well.

The Swift method first(where:) in O(n)complexity
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first, whereas a binary search has a worst-case performance of O(log n)‎ and a best-case performance of O(1)‎.

So assuming :

```
struct Player {
var id : Int
var name : String
}
```

for :

```
var players : [Player] = [
    Player(id: 0, name: "Bob"),
    Player(id: 1, name: "Edd"),
    Player(id: 2, name: "Jo"),
    Player(id: 3, name: "John")
]
```

Solution recursive :

```
func getPlayername(_ id : Int,  _ players : [Player]) -> String?{
    guard players.count > 0 else {
     print("No players found with id \(id)")
     return nil
    }
    if players.first!.id == id {
        return players.first?.name
    }else{
        return getPlayername(id, Array(players.dropFirst()))
    }
}
print(getPlayername(3, players))
```

Solution binary :

```
func getPlayerBinary(_ id : Int,  _ players : [Player]) -> String?{
    var startIndex = 0
    var max = players.count

    while startIndex < max {
      let midIndex = startIndex + (max - startIndex) / 2
        if players[midIndex].id == id {
            return players[midIndex].name
        } else if players[midIndex].id < id {
        lowerBound = midIndex + 1
      } else {
        max = midIndex
      }
    }
    print("No players found with id \(id)")
    return nil
}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

Comment: That is not a binary search.

Comment: Right right, Editing the binary option now :)

Comment: If you're going to spend the time to implement binary search, I'd opt to at least make it generic, so it has more reuse value

Comment: Various implementations here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31904396/1187415.

Answer (score -1):

```
let name = team.roster.first(where: { $0["player_id"] == id}).map{ $0["player_name"] }
```

Comment: Why should this be more efficient?

Comment: I did think of this, but wasn't sure how this is more efficient like @MartinR is asking. Would this not do the same thing, just with less lines of code?