# How can I group messages by date?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting

Let's say that I am fetching messages (objects) from a database. They do not arrive at the same time, a message always arrives alone (one fetch -> one message; a function gets called for every message) and at any time. 
Every message contains a time stamp that represents the date when the message was created. So I can call `message.date` and I will get the date when the message was created.
The messages do not arrive in any order; it can be that the created last message is at the third/fourth/... position.

I'd like to group these messages by day in order to present them in a `UITableView`. 
Each section represents a day. Eeach section header includes the day and every cell includes the time (kind of like in WhatsApp Messenger).
I know how to create custom header views, insert sections, rows etc. 
The problem is that I don't know how or as what data type to sort the messages in order to create the TableView easily ***and*** resource-saving and efficient (in terms of storage requirement and clarity).
It would be easy if I had a two-dimensional array, but I am not clever enough to think up an efficient approach to sort (or rather group) the messages.

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time stamp is a date, so sort by date (array) and group by day (dictionary).

- Sorting an array that includes date information by date is a one-liner in Swift.
- Grouping a sorted array that includes date information into a dictionary keyed by day is also a one-liner in Swift.

So that's two lines of code, and you didn't have to change anything.

However, a dictionary has no order, so I would then suggest taking a third step where you transform the dictionary into an array of some custom struct reflecting the section-row structure of your table. The correct data source for *any* sectioned table view is going to have a structure like this:

```
struct Row {
    // row properties
}
struct Section {
    var rowData : [Row]
    // section properties
}
var model : [Section]!
```

So after you've made your dictionary as a way of grouping, you just map it onto an array of Section and maintain that going forward.

Of course if you have *no* data to start with and the data arrives one item at a time, then you can omit the two bulleted steps above. Just start with the structured model and keep slotting each item into the right spot as it arrives.

*EDIT:* You expressed interest (in a comment) on how to insert an element into the right place in an already sorted array, so here's an example (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26679191/341994):

```
extension Array {
    func insertionIndex(of elem: Element, by f: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> Int {
        var lo = 0
        var hi = self.count - 1
        while lo <= hi {
            let mid = (lo + hi)/2
            if f(self[mid], elem) {
                lo = mid + 1
            } else if f(elem, self[mid]) {
                hi = mid - 1
            } else {
                return mid // found at position mid
            }
        }
        return lo // not found, would be inserted at position lo
    }
    mutating func insertSorted(_ elem:Element, by f: (Element, Element) -> Bool) {
        self.insert(elem, at:self.insertionIndex(of:elem, by:f))
    }
}
```

Here's a test; of course your ordering function won't be as simple as `<` but that's really the only difference:

```
var arr = [Int]()
arr.insertSorted(1, by:<)
arr.insertSorted(10, by:<)
arr.insertSorted(9, by:<)
arr.insertSorted(3, by:<)
arr.insertSorted(5, by:<)
arr.insertSorted(7, by:<)
arr.insertSorted(6, by:<)
// [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Ok. Just to make it clear; I'd have to sort the messages array by date every time a new message arrives?

Comment: Mmmmm, not necessarily; if you're already sorted, you just slot the new message in where it belongs.

Comment: That sounds great. How would I insert a new message?

Comment: There are well-known algorithms for quickly finding the right place to insert an item into a list of sorted items. That's the least of your worries.

Comment: Just thinking about this.. I definitely have no data to start with. The third step seems very logic ;-) I think I can make it! Thanks, I'll just add another comment if questions arise. (And I'll also check your answer asa I have a solution).

Comment: Added an example of how to keep inserting into a sorted array.

Comment: But what if there are messages with the same day? If I call `insertSorted()`, it won't be added to the section that already exists, but it will be added before.

Comment: Look at the structure I am suggesting you use. The Section struct has section properties. Your sections are days, so your Section will have a `day` property. So first you look to see if you have a Section whose `day` is this day. If there is, you insert the message into to its `rowData`. If there is not, you create a new Section and insert it in its proper place and add the message to its `rowData`.

Comment: Yeah, you're the best. I made it ;-) Thanks a lot! That's a great answer! @matt

Comment: Hey @matt, some time later, I am now wondering how it's possible to add several rows at once (and updating the table view for every single row). May sound easy, but I am experiencing problems when simply storing the insertion index path in a variable and then calling tableView.insert(at:indexPath,:_) because there can be several index paths with the exact same row and section. I would have to update the index paths somehow afterwards, when I inserted every element into my array.

Comment: Yes, I saw your other question. :) The problem is that you are inserting sorted so you don't know _what row_ you just inserted into the model. Thus you have no way of telling the batch update that information when you try to modify the table.

Comment: I do know that; my insertSorted function returns an `IndexPath` with a section and a row number. The problem is that when I add more and more messages, another message can get the same `IndexPath`. Then I got two similar IndexPaths, so `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will only get the last added message and this will result in an error because `numberOfRows inSection` looks up the number of rows from my model. But I have no idea how to fix that. I could call `index(of: ...)` in the end, when every element was inserted, but I absolutely like that solution. I hope that was understandable.

Comment: So when adding elements to my array, the `IndexPath` for the first added element can change when adding more elements before the first element (when the array grows). That's my problem. And then I have the same `IndexPath` several times.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy you can grouped it.
for example messages contain these following:

```
struct message {
    let senderName:String
    let mess:String
    let reciever:String
    let time:Date
}
```

and you have some messages:

```
var messages = [message]()
        messages.append(message(senderName: "snow", mess: "Hello", reciever: "Dani", time: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1533078663)))
        messages.append(message(senderName: "john", mess: "Hello", reciever: "Dani", time: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1533078606)))
        messages.append(message(senderName: "alix", mess: "Hello", reciever: "Dani", time: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1533078633)))
```

you can grouped it easily by using this:

```
let groupedMessage = Dictionary(grouping: messages) { (mess) -> Date in
   return mess.time
}
```