# Does array.count and array[0 ...< index] slow down a binary search?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, testing, binary-search

today I did a test for a job and was asked to search through an array of integers, this is the question:

> The goal of this exercise is to check the presence of a number in an
>   array.
>
> **Specifications:**
>
> The items are integers arranged in **ascending** order.
>
> The array can contain up to 1 million items
>
> Implement the function **existsInArray(_ numbers: [Int], _ k: Int)** so
>   that it returns **true** if **k** belongs to **numbers**, otherwise the function
>   should return **false**.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> let numbers = [-9, 14, 37, 102]
> existsInArray(numbers, 102) // returns true
> existsInArray(numbers, 36) //returns false
> ```
>
> Note: Try to save CPU cycles

Alright, so I gave my answer which is the code below and waited for the result

```
func existsInArray(_ numbers: [Int], _ k: Int) -> Bool {
    if numbers.isEmpty {
        return false
    }
    let numbersHalfIndex: Int = (numbers.count/2)
    if k == numbers[numbersHalfIndex] {
        return true
    } else if k != numbers[0] && numbers.count == 1 {
        return false
    } else if k <= numbers[numbersHalfIndex] {
        let leftHalfNumbersArray = numbers[0 ..< numbersHalfIndex]
        return existsInArray(Array(leftHalfNumbersArray), k)
    } else if k > numbers[numbersHalfIndex] {
        let rightHalfNumbersArray = numbers[numbersHalfIndex ..< numbers.count]
        return existsInArray(Array(rightHalfNumbersArray), k)
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

So turns out that *"The solution doesn't work in a reasonable time with one million items"* and now I don't know what I did wrong since binary search is fast as f*ck.

My only guess is that maybe **number.count** or **numbers[0 ...< numbersHalfIndex]** or **numbers[numbersHalfIndex ...< number.count]** makes everything go slower than expected.

Am I tripping or something?

Edit:
If anyone is curious I tested my code and Martin R code to see how much of an impact using ArraySlice have in terms of time.
I used an array of 100.000.000 itens in ascending order starting from 0. 
Here is how I captured the time:

```
print("////////// MINE //////////")
var startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
print(existsInArray(numbers, 0))
var timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
print("Time elapsed for mine: \(timeElapsed) s.")

print("////////// Martin R //////////")
counter = 0
startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
print(existsInArrayOptimal(numbers, 0))
timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
print("Time elapsed for Martin R: \(timeElapsed) s.")
```

And here is the result:

> ////////// MINE //////////
>
> true
>
> Time elapsed for mine:
>
> 1.2008800506591797 s.
>
> ////////// Martin R //////////
>
> true
>
> Time elapsed for Martin R: 0.00012993812561035156 s.

It's about 1000x faster!

Comment: Are you testing it on a playground? Have you tried using endIndex instead of count?

Comment: Btw you are initializing a new array with its slice

Comment: Converting the slices back into arrays with `Array(...)` is the slowest thing you're doing in there.  It would be much better if you did all of the work on the slices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing `number.count` is not a problem because that is a O(1) operation for arrays. And slicing with `numbers[0 ...< numbersHalfIndex]` is not a problem either. But `Array(leftHalfNumbersArray)` creates a new array from the slice, and that copies all the elements.

There are two possible ways to avoid that:

- Update array *indices* (for lower and upper bound of the current search range) instead of creating arrays which are passed down the recursion.
- Pass array *slices* down the recursion. Slices share the elements with the original array (as long as they are not mutated).

A demonstration of the second approach:

```
func existsInArray(_ numbers: ArraySlice<Int>, _ k: Int) -> Bool {
    if numbers.isEmpty {
        return false
    }
    let numbersHalfIndex = numbers.startIndex + numbers.count / 2
    if k == numbers[numbersHalfIndex] {
        return true
    } else if k < numbers[numbersHalfIndex] {
        return existsInArray(numbers[..<numbersHalfIndex], k)
    } else {
        return existsInArray(numbers[(numbersHalfIndex + 1)...], k)
    }
}
```

Note that array slices share their indices with the original array so that the indices do not necessarily start at zero. That's why `numbers.startIndex` is used for the index calculation.

And a wrapper function which takes a “real” array argument:

```
func existsInArray(_ numbers: [Int], _ k: Int) -> Bool {
    return existsInArray(numbers[...], k)
}
```

As @Leo suggested, you can implement this as a collection method instead of implementing two separate methods. Collection indices are not necessarily integers, but for a `RandomAccessCollection` the index calculations are guaranteed to be O(1). You can also generalize it to collections of arbitrary comparable elements instead of integers.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Element: Comparable {
    /// Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the collection contains the
    /// given element. It is assumed that the collection elements are sorted
    /// in ascending (non-decreasing) order. 
    ///
    /// - Parameter element: The element to find in the collection.
    /// - Returns: `true` if the element was found in the collection; otherwise,
    ///   `false`.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(log(*n*)), where *n* is the size of the collection.
    func binarySearch(for element: Element) -> Bool {
        if isEmpty {
            return false
        }
        let midIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: count / 2)
        if element == self[midIndex] {
            return true
        } else if element < self[midIndex] {
            return self[..<midIndex].binarySearch(for: element)
        } else {
            return self[index(after: midIndex)...].binarySearch(for: element)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let numbers = [-9, 14, 37, 102]
print(numbers.binarySearch(for: 102)) // true
print(numbers.binarySearch(for: 36))  // false
```

Alternatively a non-recursive method which updates the indices of the search range:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Element: Comparable {
    func binarySearch(for element: Element) -> Bool {
        var lo = startIndex
        var hi = endIndex

        while lo < hi {
            let mid = index(lo, offsetBy: distance(from: lo, to: hi) / 2)
            if element == self[mid] {
                return true
            } else if element < self[mid] {
                hi = mid
            } else {
                lo = index(after: mid)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's it.
Turns out creating a new array is slow enough to trigger a bad answer.

Comment: Oh I almost forgot, how should I pass the indexes if I want to keep the function as func existsInArray(_ numbers: [Int], _ k: Int) -> Bool ?

Comment: @DouglasPfeifer: Then you would define a `func existsInArray(_ numbers: [Int], lowIndex: Int, highIndex: Int  _ k: Int) -> Bool` function. Or without recursion, similarly as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26679191/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR instead of creating two methods you could create a generic one that would accept any collection. Something like `func exists<C: Collection, I: FixedWidthInteger>(in elements: C, _ k: I) -> Bool where C.Element: FixedWidthInteger, C.Index == Int {
    guard !elements.isEmpty else { return false }
    let  halfIndex = elements.startIndex + elements.count / 2
    return  k == elements[halfIndex] ? true :
            k < elements[halfIndex] ?
            exists(in: elements[..<halfIndex], k) :
        exists(in: elements[halfIndex.advanced(by: 1)...], k)
}`

Comment: or extending FixedWidthInteger `extension FixedWidthInteger {
    func exists<C: Collection>(in elements: C) -> Bool where C.Element == Self, C.Index == Int {
        if elements.isEmpty { return false }
        let halfIndex = elements.startIndex + elements.count / 2
        return self == elements[halfIndex] ? true :
               self < elements[halfIndex] ?
        exists(in: elements[..<halfIndex]) :
        exists(in: elements[halfIndex.advanced(by: 1)...])
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus: Thanks for the suggestions, you are of course right. (My intention was mainly to explain the problem, not to provide the most general binary search method.)

Comment: @MartinR Instead of constraining `Index == Int` we can do `let midIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: count / 2)` and `index(after: midIndex)` Is there a `RandomAccessCollection` that's not `Int` indexed?

Comment: @LeoDabus: That's exactly what I was just thinking about :)

Comment: Isn't *slicing* still a bit more efficient in the non-recursive version? `func binarySearch(for element: Element) -> Bool { var slice : SubSequence = self[...]  while !slice.isEmpty { let mid = slice.index(slice.startIndex, offsetBy: slice.count / 2) if element == slice[mid] { return true } else if element < slice[mid] { slice = slice[index(after: mid)...] } else { slice = slice[..<mid] } } return false }`

Comment: @vadian: A quick benchmark showed no difference (but note that there is an error in your code, the two else blocks must be exchanged). However, the non-recursive version is significantly faster than the recursive version.

Comment: `Slice` has been promoted so enthusiasticly on WWDC that I assumed it provides benefit in all situations where a subsequence is needed. You're right about the error. This comes from quickly c&p things together. 